# MSSQl 'GO' handling in Powershell connection String

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a sql query which is patched with a `Go` to check the orphan objects in mssql.

```
use DBName
go
sp_change_users_login 'report'
```

Now, I am automating the above in Powershell for all the user databases and trying to get the orphan users.

Here is the code:

```
        if($port)
        {
        $connectionString ="server=$servername,$port;Integrated Security=true;" #uid=$DBUserName; pwd=$dbpwd;Database=$DB;
        }
        else
        {
        $connectionString ="server=$servername;Integrated Security=true;" 
        }
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ea Stop
        $connection.ConnectionString=$connectionString
        $connection.Open()

        $db_query = @"
        Select name from sys.sysdatabases where dbid > 4 and name not in ('ReportServer')
"@
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $db_query
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $object= New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $object.Load($result)
        [System.Array]$DBs = $object.name

        if($DBs -is [System.Array])
        {
            foreach($DB in $DBs)
            {
            ## PROBLEM IS HERE ###
              $orphan_users_query = @"

                use $DB
                GO
                sp_change_users_login 'report'

"@
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $orphan_users_query
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $object= New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $object.Load($result)
        $object | Out-File C:\temp\outfile_property.txt -Append -Force
            }
        }
```

Problem is PS cannot identify the `go` separator because it is specific to MSSQL/SSMS.  So, how can I still iterate and run the query in all user databases without creating multiple connections specific to each DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`ChangeDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the connection is an alternate means of switching databases.

You can then just execute `sp_change_users_login` as is. No need for `GO`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really wish to avoid changing the DBs using connection string and wish to handle it in sql queries. Is there any other mean to progress? If changing DB is handled, then I can ignore the Go completely like you have stated.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - I don't understand the objection. It's literally just `$connection.ChangeDatabase($DB)`.

Comment: Problem is Product Owner is kinda trying to avoid it :P . Nothing else. Anyways, I will accept this answer cause it makes sense.